# How to find a 2x2 pattern in nested lists

Tags: python, list, indexing

Using a nested list like:

`lst = [["S", "V", "G", "S"], ["V", "G", "S", "V"], ["V", "G", "G", "S"], ["V", "V", "V", "V"]]`

I have written a code to express it as a grid like:

```
   S  V  S  S  
   V  G  G  V       
   V  G  G  S       
   V  V  V  V
```

I'm trying to write a code that can detect the 2x2 of Gs and replace them with Xs, however I seem to always result with index errors in the process.

```
for row, lst_row in enumerate(lst):
        for col, item in enumerate(lst_row):
            if item == lst[row][col + 1] and col + 1 < len(lst_row) and row + 1 < len(lst):
                
                right = lst_row[col + 1]
                down = lst[row + 1][col]
                down_right = lst[row + 1][col + 1]
                
                if item == right and item == down and item == down_right:
                    item == "X"
                    right == "X"
                    down == "X"
                    down_right == "X"
```

I assume it's something wrong with line 3 of this code block but I'm struggling to understand how the index can still be out of range. Any help would be greatly appreciated, cheers

Edit: The error message is "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: You're trying to look at the next column before you check that there *is* a next column.

Comment: (And `item == "X"` doesn't replace anything either, for multiple reasons.)

Comment: Yeah just realised ` item == "X" ` won't work but my code never got to that point for me to check haha

Comment: You check `item == lst[row][col + 1]` before `col + 1 < len(lst_row) and row + 1 < len(lst)`. This will clearly result in index errors when the latter condition is not true.

Comment: @vAlkanol do you want it for a 4x4 matrix or an nxn matrix?

Comment: Thanks Unmitigated that cleared things up for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from itertools import pairwise

lst = [["S", "V", "G", "S"], ["V", "G", "G", "V"], ["V", "G", "G", "S"], ["V", "V", "V", "V"]]

for rows in pairwise(lst):
    for j, block in enumerate(pairwise(zip(*rows))):
        if block == (('G',) * 2,) * 2:
            for row in rows:
                row[j:j+2] = 'XX'

for row in lst:
    print(row)
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVBBDoIwEIzXvmLDhVbxwsmYcOYBRmPScEBTYhFoU0qIfsWLF32Ur7GbImLiHuYwO7OzmdtTX-xJNff7o7PFcvWabQujapBWGKtU1YKstTIWdC5NL1tBSNVaSIDzYBNEEOwQUoRNkEXAJ0Tq9__YqXYKWUZIoQwY1bvkZkylLpStCbjBdRnBoVLHM0pE09XC5FbQUXyVms7xBGODCUcWgylJgNIwDSMGc4g9fmWfDOfH83jmd4njWF6uy0WcuSrC_T4c30aPe9ZbtJGNpY5lvt2h5E_Zbw)):

```
['S', 'V', 'G', 'S']
['V', 'X', 'X', 'V']
['V', 'X', 'X', 'S']
['V', 'V', 'V', 'V']
```

About your error here:

```
item == lst[row][col + 1] and col + 1 < len(lst_row)
```

[EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-EAFP) works. [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-LBYL) works. But you tried LAYL. "Look ***after*** you leap". Doesn't work. You should check whether `col + 1` is valid ***before*** you use it, not after having used it without safety.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense, thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```py
from itertools import product

lst = [["S", "V", "G", "S"], ["V", "G", "G", "V"], ["V", "G", "G", "S"], ["V", "V", "V", "V"]]

n = len(lst)  # assumes square list of lists 

for row,col in product(range(n-1), range(n-1)):
    if lst[row][col] == lst[row+1][col] and lst[row][col] == lst[row][col+1] and lst[row][col] == lst[row+1][col+1]:
        lst[row][col] = "X"
        lst[row+1][col] = "X"
        lst[row][col+1] = "X"
        lst[row+1][col+1] = "X"
```

or if you want it all as 1 in a line:

```py
for row,col in product(range(n-1), range(n-1)):
    if lst[row][col] == lst[row+1][col] == lst[row][col+1] == lst[row+1][col+1]:
        lst[row][col] = lst[row+1][col] = lst[row][col+1] = lst[row+1][col+1] = "X"
```